# Increase table row height but not separation from surrounding text

Tags: tables, lists, environments

I would like to construct a table environment that accepts an argument that controls the vertical space between rows but does not influence the vertical separation of the table from the surrounding text.  The general position of the table with respect to surrounding text is to be controlled (exclusively) by an enclosing list environment. The following effort using `\arraystretch` to control the inter-row spacing fails, as does using the alternative `\extrarowheight`.  Both control sequences impinge upon the vertical separation of the table from surrounding text:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newenvironment{mytable}[1]{%
    \begin{list}{}{%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{2em}
        \setlength{\topsep}{5pt}            %desired vertical separation of table from
    }                                       %surrounding text   
        \item
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}    %desired vertical space between rows
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
}{%
        \end{tabular}
    \end{list}
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{mytable}{3}
    R1C1 & R1C2 \\
    R2C1 & R2C2 \\
    R3C1 & R3C2
\end{mytable}

\lipsum[1] 
\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: neither extrarowheight nor arraystretch affect the space beween the table and the surrounding text, but they do make the first row higher, not just later rows. The change is by a known amount though so you can simply add a negative skip of that amount before the table.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  But that "known amount" is subject to the `\arraystretch` factor, which may vary between applications of the environment within the document.

Comment: No, the arraystretch is what I meant is the _known amount_ the top row is `\arraystretch\ht\strutbox-\ht\strutbox` higher than it would be, so you can just remove that space.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  And this could be done globally within the preamble?  Would you mind showing me explicitly? I'm not well-versed with strutbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want something like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newenvironment{mytable}[1]{%
    \begin{list}{}{%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{2em}
        \setlength{\topsep}{5pt}            %desired vertical separation of table from
    }                                       %surrounding text   
        \item\mbox{}%
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}    %desired vertical space between rows
\par
\vspace{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-\arraystretch\ht\strutbox-\parskip-\baselineskip}%
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
}{%
        \end{tabular}
\par
\vspace{\dimexpr\dp\strutbox-\arraystretch\dp\strutbox}%
    \end{list}
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{mytable}{3}
    R1C1 & R1C2 \\
    R2C1 & R2C2 \\
    R3C1 & R3C2
\end{mytable}

\lipsum[1] 
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's very nice, David.  Thank you for providing the particulars. May I inquire as to the purpose of the `\mbox{}`?

Comment: You need to get out of the \item and into vertical mode to add the vspace (well at least it's easier that way)

Comment: Your `\par` doesn't accomplish that?

Comment: @steven_nevets no, `\par` after `\item` does nothing

Comment: Forgive my persistence, but then why did you apply a `par`?

Comment: so vspace works in an understandable way, in vertical mode.

Answer (score 3):

Two solutions, with the `cellspace` package, which defines *minimal* vertical spacings at the top or the bottom of cells, or with `makecell`, which defines vertical spacings to *add* at the top or the bottom of cells:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\newenvironment{mytable}[1]{%
    \begin{list}{}{%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{2em}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{1cm}%desired minimal vertical space between rows
        \setlength{\topsep}{5pt} %desired vertical separation of table from
    } %surrounding text
        \item
        \begin{tabular}{SlSl}
}{%
        \end{tabular}
\vspace*{-\cellspacebottomlimit}
    \end{list}
}

\usepackage{makecell}
\newenvironment{myothertable}[1]{%
    \begin{list}{}{%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{2em}
        \setlength{\topsep}{5pt} %desired vertical separation of table from
\newlength\arrayskip
\setlength\arrayskip{#1}
\setcellgapes[b]{#1}
\makegapedcells
    } %surrounding text
        \item%
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
}{%
        \end{tabular}
\vspace*{-\arrayskip}
    \end{list}
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{mytable}{1}
    R1C1 & R1C2 \\
    R2C1 & R2C2 \\
    R3C1 & R3C2
\end{mytable}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{myothertable}{1cm}
    R1C1 & R1C2 \\
    R2C1 & R2C2 \\
    R3C1 & R3C2
\end{myothertable}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing these solutions, Bernard.  They both work nicely, and I intend to look into these packages.